# Taurus - JMeter properties set via command line are not being picked up

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter, api-testing, performance-testing, taurus

I've got a JMeter test setup with the environment details (protocol, hostname and port number) set as properties. This is so I can repeat the same test on multiple environments through a pipeline.

When I set the properties (e.g. modules.jmeter.properties.protocol: https) in .bzt-rc or any other yaml file, then Taurus picks them up just fine. However, if I then run the test using bzt -o modules.jmeter.properties.protocol=TEST then the test runs just fine (I'd expect it to break as I'm overriding the property setting).

If I remove the setting of the property from the file (e.g. .bzt-rc) but keep the command line setting then the test does not work even though I am now setting the protocol correctly (-o modules.jmeter.properties.protocol=https).

I've looked at this link https://gettaurus.org/docs/CommandLine/ and can't see anything obvious but I'm sure there must be.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, looking at this again, I had the properties for protocol, hostname and port set as: modules.jmeter.properties.environment.protocol and same for hostname. For port, I had modules.jmeter.properties.environment.port..

This naming convention worked fine when I set the properties in a text file as a single line. I.e...

```
modules.jmeter.properties.environment.protocol=https
modules.jmeter.properties.environment.hostname=<my-hostname>.com
modules.jmeter.properties.environment.port.<microservice-name>=<my-port-number>
```

However, when I passed them in via command line, the effective.yml file was treating each . separator as you can see below (copied out of the effective.yml):

```
  environment:
    hostname: <my-hostname>.com
    port:
      <microservice-name>: <my-port-number>
    protocol: https
```

I've found that when I change the properties to just be hostname, microservice-port and protocol (i.e. no nesting) then it works fine when I pass them in via command line.

E.g. -o modules.jmeter.properties.protocol=https

So, I've changed my JMeter property names to just be protocol, hostname and port-number and it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. > if I then run the test using bzt -o modules.jmeter.properties.protocol=TEST then the test runs just fine

   that shouldn't happen as you will get [MalformedURLException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/MalformedURLException.html)

   [image]

   overall [status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) of the `bzt` command execution will still be `0` (success) unless you have custom [pass/fail criteria](https://gettaurus.org/docs/PassFail/)
2. > If I remove the setting of the property from the file (e.g. .bzt-rc) but keep the command line setting then the test does not work even though I am now setting the protocol correctly

   that shouldn't happen as well, you don't need to declare the property anywhere, you can just **set** its value via `-o` command-line argument (like [`-J` command-line argument for JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)), you can double-check it by inspecting `effective.json` or `effective.yml` file, you will see that any property(ies) you set via `-o` argument(s) will be added to the default set of JMeter properties overrides

Just in case make sure to have the [latest version of Taurus installed](https://gettaurus.org/install/Installation/) as you might be suffering from a bug which has been fixed already and get familiarized with [Navigating your First Steps Using Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus) article.

Further assistance is not possible without seeing your .yml file and the way you're referring the property either in YAML or in .JMX

Comment: Thanks for the above. I've done some more investigation today and think I've found the problem - see answer below.